# Not receiving Stack Exchange mail

Tags: bug, email

I am not able to receive a password setting e-mail in my registered mail account not even in junk folder or in-box and anywhere using `forget password` option in stack-exchange login, I can only login via  face-book which I don't want to use.It is a bug that I am not receiving password set up link in my registered mail account?I am very serious about this being repeated request at forget password option and not receiving any mail?

Comment: The log says you were emailed 4 times. Are you sure you're checking the right email? Did they go to spam?

Comment: @Seth I am checking the registered email associated with this account but had never received the link in any of the folders inbox.junk,spam etc. checked filter also whether it is in blocked list but found nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say then. The site says it emailed you..